# Visual C++ 2008 as frontend for Access

Tags: c++, ms-access, frontend, visual-c++-2008

I am working on a database project that requires me to code in C++. I have the framework for the relational database built using Microsoft Access. Since I would like a GUI for the user, I am trying to use Visual C++ 2008 to build it.

I have tried to build a solution as a win32 console app, MFC app, and CLR app, each halting me with their various errors.

I have scoured the web for help but to no avail. If anyone could give me some direction or, better yet, a link to a good tutorial, it would be much appreciated.

Ben

Comment: I would indicate what problems you're having. Can't help, if you don't tell us what the issue is.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular to use Access as the database engine? Unless you are going to be the only user, I would suggest SQL Server, either the Compact or Express editions. You could still open the SQL Server database using linked tables in Access to view/edit/add rows.

Comment: Why does your project require you to code in C++?

Comment: I think Access is the best front end for Access. Is there a reason why does your project require VC++?

Comment: The following link might help: [Linking to an Ms-Access Data Source using Visual C++ 2008 Windows Forms Application](http://reydacoco.blogspot.com/2011/10/linking-to-ms-access-data-source-using.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599.aspx) about developing C / C++ apps that connect to Microsoft Access.  Hope this helps.